# Make to 2d arrays equal using backtracking

Tags: python, backtracking

I'm having problems trying to use backtracking in python.
Here is the problem: I have to make two matrices equal by only moving the zero(up, down, left and right), for exemple:

```
Matrix1:  [ [1,2],
            [3,0]]
Matrix2:  [ [1,0],
            [3,2]]
```

number of moves: 3 (you can't use more than x moves)

The matrix1 needs to be equal to matrix2.

The anwser should be:

`'u' (move zero upwards)`

I have no idea how to begin :c

PS: Sorry, this isn’t my first language, so feel free to correct me.

`Matrix size:
Number of movements:
First Matrice:
Final Matrice:'`

If the inputs are:
3
3
1 2 3
4 5 6
7 8 0

1 2 3
4 0 5
7 8 6

the output should be:
`ul`  (zero change position with 6, moving upwards, and then zero changes position with 5, moving to the left).

I don't how to use backtrack.

I'm trying to do something like this:

```
def safe(x, y, n): 
    if x>=0 and x<n and y>=n and y<n:  
        return True  
    return False  

def whereszero(maze): 

    for x in range(len(maze)):  
        for y in range(len(maze)):  
            if maze[x][y]==0:  
              return x, y  



def main():  
    n=int(input("Matrice size:"))  #matrice dimensions  
    matrice1=[int(x) for x in input().split()] for j in range(n)]  
    matrice2=[int(x) for x in input().split()] for j in range(n)]  
    max=int(input("maximum movements:"))  
    zerox, zeroy=whereszero(matrice1) #returns zero index  
    if solved(matrice1, matrice2, zeroX, zeroY, zeroX, zeroY, 0, max, b, list)==False:  
        print("No solution")  
        return False  
    print("Anwser:", list)  
    return True  


def solved(mat1, mat2, zeroinx, zeroiny, x, y, i, max, movements, list):  
    if mat1==mat2:  
        return True  
    if safe(x, y, len(mat1)) and i<=max
        mat1[x][y], mat1[zeroinx][zeroiny]=mat1[zeroinx][zeroiny], mat1[x][y]  
        zeroinx=x  
        zeroint=y  
        list.append("movements")  
            if solved(mat1, mat2, zeroinx, zeroiny, x+1, y, i+1, max, d, list): #try moving downwards  
                return True  
            if solved(mat1, mat2, zeroinx, zeroiny, x-1, y, i+1, max, u, list): #try moving upwards...  
                return True  
            if solve(mat1, mat2, zeroinx, zeroiny, x, y-1, i+1, max, l, list): #left
                return True  
            if solve(mat1, mat2, zeroinx, zeroiny, x, y+1, i+1, max, r, list): #right, i is the number of moviments tried, max is maximum number of movements  
                return True  

        return False # How do I backtrack?  


main()   `
```

Comment: Will the arrays always be `2x2`, will there be more than one 0?

Comment: There's only one 0 and the arrays can have any dimension (2x2, 3x3, 4x4), but they have to be square matrices.

Comment: Questions asking for homework help must include a summary of the work you've done so far to solve the problem, and a description of the difficulty you are having solving it. https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Comment: Im trying this, but doesn't work :c

Answer (score 0):

Backtracking is a technique, where - to be short - your algorithm make some choice of possible ones, but if that choice doesn't lead to success, it comes back (hence the backtracking name) and try next possible choice, until success or all choices will be tried. Typical solution in pseudo-code:

```
func run(state):
    if success: return true
    for choice in possible-choices(state):
        new_state = execute_choice(state, choice)
        if run(new_state):
            return true
    return false
```

Things to keep in mind:

1. typical solution is recursive, so there's a limit of maximum depth, that you can check (based on memory).
2. you need to stop checking new 'possible-choices' at some point. For example in your task given matrix 2x2 you can imagine going with 0 left, right, left, right in neverending cycle. You need to either set a hard limit or detect previously encounered state.
3. `new_state` is named like this for a reason - you need **copy**. You need to remember 'old' state, so you could come back to it. How do you keep it in memory is another story.